# Destroying a FastButton event

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

I've been using the Google FastButton code to add instant clicks on mobile devices for some time now, but I've never been able to get the destroy method to work.

Can anyone give me any pointers on how to remove a FastButton event from an element? I'm using Alex Black's jQuery wrapper (https://github.com/alexblack/google-fastbutton) to add a 'fastClick' to an element, so it would be even better if I could work out how to destroy through that.

Many thanks,

T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use unbind() to remove the fastClick handler from your button i.e.

```
$('#mybutton').unbind('fastClick');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I think I was trying to unbind "FastButton" when I tried that approach. This one works great.